# add input fields dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms, addition

Following code help me adding more input fields but when submit it does not bring all the input data record. please help to figure it out and understand.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addmore").click(function(){
//      alert(counters);
        $("li").append("<li><input type='text' id='hd' name='hd' value='heading' onClick='this.select();'> <input type='text' id='amount' name='amount' value='amount' onClick='this.select();'></li>");
    });

    $("#submit").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counters; i++){
            msg += $('#hd' + i).val() + $('#amount' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
     });
});

<button id="addmore">+</button>
<form method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="hd1" name="hd1" value="heading" onClick="this.select();">
            <input type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" value="amount" onClick="this.select();">
        </li>
    </ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: where is the variable 'counters' coming from?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you add all new inputs with the same id's?

Comment: its there before document.ready and its var counters = 1

Comment: all inputs comes from jquery append

Comment: Just a sample from jQuery: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: Based on jQuery dialog modal form here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/UecWe/3/

Answer (score 2):

Here's working example , try this.......

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function deleterow(id){
        var to_del='row_id_'+id;
        $(to_del).destroy();
        var count_row = document.getElementById('count_row').value;
        count_row--;
        //alert(count_row);
        document.getElementById('count_row').value = count_row;
    } 
    function deletefirstrow(first_row)
    {
    $(first_row).destroy();
    var count_row = document.getElementById('count_row').value;
    count_row--;
    //alert(count_row);
    document.getElementById('count_row').value = count_row;
    } 
    function addrow()
    {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var count_row = document.getElementById('count_row').value;
    count_row++;
    //alert(count_row);
    document.getElementById('count_row').value = count_row;
    var content = '<div id="row_id_'+count_row+'"><select id="sweet_type[]" name="sweet_type[]" style="width:112px"><option>select item type</option><option>Besan Ladoo</option><option>Bundi Ladoo</option></select>&nbsp;<select id="order_type[]" name="order_type[]" style="width:123px"><option>select order type</option><option>1 kg</option><option>1/2 kg</option></select>&nbsp;<input type="text" id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]" size="10" value="" class="inputbox" maxlength="100" style="width:50px"/>&nbsp;<label class="button" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="deleterow('+count_row+')">Delete</label></div>';
    div.innerHTML = content;
    var container = document.getElementById('rowcontaniner');
    container.appendChild(div);
    } 
</script>
<form action="/order-form.html" method="POST" id="submitForm" name="submitForm" class="form-validate" onsubmit="return validate_form()" >
  <div class="form_div_content " id="vScroll" style="width:790px; height:282px;">
    <!-- Form Field Row Start -->
    <div class="form_row" style="height:280px;">
 <table>
    <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div id="to_del_firstrow">
                    <select class="" style="width:112px" id="sweet_type[]" name="sweet_type[]">
                     <option>select item type</option>
                      <option>Besan Ladoo</option>
                      <option>Bundi Ladoo</option>                      
                    </select>
                    <select style="width:123px" id="order_type[]" name="order_type[]">
                      <option>select order type</option>
                      <option>1 kg</option>
                      <option>1/2 kg</option>
                    </select>
                    <input style="width:50px" id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]" size="10" value="" class="inputbox" maxlength="100" type="text">
                    <input id="price[]" name="price[]" size="10" value="" class="inputbox" maxlength="100" type="hidden">
                    <input id="total[]" name="total[]" size="10" value="" class="inputbox" maxlength="100" type="hidden">
                    <label class="button" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="deletefirstrow('to_del_firstrow')">Delete</label>
                  </div>
                  <div id="rowcontaniner">
                  <div></div>
                  </div>
                  </td>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div id="add_row_items" class="form_add button" style="padding:0 5px; margin-right:12px;" onClick="addrow()">
            <label style="cursor:pointer" for="add"> ADD ITEMS</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="count_row" name="count_row" />
</tbody>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counters = 0;
    var msg = '';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        counters = 0;
        $("#addmore").click(function() {
            counters = counters + 1;
            $("li").append("<ul><input type='text' id='hd" + counters + "' name='hd' value='heading'>" +
                               "<input type='text' id='amount" + counters + "' name='amount' value='amount'></ul>");
        });

        $("#submit").click(function() {
            msg = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= counters; i++) {
                msg += $('#hd' + i).val() + ' ' + $('#amount' + i).val() + ' ';
            }
            alert(msg);
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="+" id="addmore" />
    <form method="post" action="">
    <li>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
var nodes = $('#formid input,#formid textarea,#formid select');
                    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

                            arr[i].id = nodes[i].id;
                            arr[i].value=nodes[i].value;
                    }
```

you'll hav all the data in arr

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `append` `li` in `ul` not in `li`

```
$("#addmore").click(function(){
     var i=$('li').length+1;
     str="<li>";
     str+="<input type='text' id='hd"+i+"' name='hd"+i+"' value='heading' onClick='this.select();'>";
     str+="<input type='text' id='amount"+i+"' name='amount"+i+"' value='amount' onClick='this.select();'></li>";
     $("ul").append(str);
});

 $("#submit").click(function () {
    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<=$('li').length; i++){
        msg += $('#hd' + i).val() + $('#amount' + i).val();
    }
    alert(msg);
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [***Working Demo***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QTBbE/) with Short and simple jQuery stuff

You are appending text-boxes with the same ID, i suggest you to not do do, Anyways your alert message for those values will go like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
     $('li').find('input').each(function () {
          alert($(this).val());
     });
});
```

Yes, it will not show the elements because Because jQuery adds them dynamically, or the View Source shows only the static elements. jQuery does not write physically the new elements. It creates them on the client-side. Let's say, virtually.

But what bothers you? If you want to see the javascript new created elements/attributes by all means, use Firefox and install the Add-on called FireBug.

Comment: one thing. adding more rows does not show html in view source mode?

Comment: see i have given description in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var counter = 1;
            $("#addmore").click(function () {
                counter++;
                var cloneText = $("li").first().clone();
                $('li').last().after(cloneText);
                $(cloneText).find('input').each(function() {

                    $(this).val('');
                    if($(this).attr('id') == 'hd1') {
                        $(this).attr('id', 'hd'+counter);
                        $(this).attr('name', 'hd'+counter);
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr('id', 'amount'+counter);
                        $(this).attr('name', 'amount'+counter);
                    }
                })
            });

           $("#submit").click(function () {
                 $('li').find('input').each(function () {
                      alert($(this).attr('id')+" = "+ $(this).val());
                });
          }); 
});
```

Try this above code. Also check in http://fiddle.jshell.net/UKXLp/